# Hide row color for column head using tabu

Tags: color, tabu

rowcolor need to be hide for column head alone using `tabu` package, first row of table body after
column head should start "cyan" color, is there any option?

`hiderowcolors` and `showrowcolors` option not working in the tabu?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\def\tabuprocesstable#1#2#3{
\taburowcolors[1]1{cyan .. white}\fontsize{8bp}{10bp}\selectfont%
#1\par%
#2\par%
#3%
}

\def\colhead{\bfseries\sffamily}

\tabuprocesstable{}{\begin{tabu}{p{100pt}p{100pt}}
\tabucline{-}
\colhead{Column head 1}&\colhead{Column head 2}\\
Total non-current&Employee benefits\vphantom{yg}\\
Total non-current&Employee benefits\\
Total non-current&Employee benefits\\
Total non-current&Employee benefits\\
\tabucline{-}
\end{tabu}}{}

\bigskip\bigskip
\tabuprocesstable{}{\begin{tabu}{p{100pt}p{100pt}}
\tabucline{-}
%\hiderowcolors
\colhead{Column head 1}&\colhead{Column head 2}\\
\colhead{Column head 3}&\colhead{Column head 4}\\
%\showrowcolors
Total non-current&Employee benefits\vphantom{yg}\\
Total non-current&Employee benefits\\
Total non-current&Employee benefits\\
Total non-current&Employee benefits\\
\tabucline{-}
\end{tabu}}{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do use tabu if you don't seem to use its X type columns? Why not go for tabularx or a simple tabular instead?

Comment: We implemented tabu pacakge and its functions for all projects using tool for all tables, is there any option using tabu itself?